# VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest & VPN inaccessibility

Tags: networking, macos, ubuntu

I am using NAT and host-only adapter, the latter is 192.168.56.* -- it works fine, but when I connect to my VPN on my host (Mac OS), the VM is inaccessible. I am assigned (on the host) a VPN IP of 10.254.250.* -- how I can get access to my VM while connected to the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the VPN Client you are using. Many Corporate policies lock down the Clients, so they cannot reach anything local while the VPN is connected. You can reach out to the Administrator of VPN connection, and see if they can allow access.